# Unable to click on any element using GetByText

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet, playwright-sharp

I am using playwright with c# .net. When I tried to click on element using getByRole or xpath, It is working fine.
When I tried using getByText or getByTitle neither it is giving error nor it is clicking on it. Please see attached image. I want to click on "Sales".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF0kH.jpg)

I tried following syntax:

```
await page.GetByText("Sales", new() { Exact = true }).ClickAsync();
await page.GetByText("Sales").ClickAsync();
```

Can someone tell me, how to use getByText?

Comment: I assume it's finding the "span" (which isn't clickable unlike the `<a>` that's around it), maybe you could try getting to the outside elements instead? Like the `<a>` or even the `nav-item`

Comment: No, It will not work for Text as there would not be text there. Text is common for all which is "Sales".

Comment: can you check if the pop up is there while you run the code, also if you can share what error you are getting that would be great ? run in debug mode to understand where is the problem because syntax is right. Also try adding the space before and after

Answer (score 0):

Here is [getByText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-by-text) detailed usage example:

Consider the following DOM structure:

```
<div>Hello <span>world</span></div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

You can locate by text substring, exact string, or a regular expression:

```
   // Matches <span>
page.getByText("world")

// Matches first <div>
page.getByText("Hello world")

// Matches second <div>
page.getByText("Hello", new Page.GetByTextOptions().setExact(true))

// Matches both <div>s
page.getByText(Pattern.compile("Hello"))

// Matches second <div>
page.getByText(Pattern.compile("^hello$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))
```

Comment: Can you please check attached image ? I am unable to click it using getText.